# emulator is not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

i got these error when i start my emulator. how to get rid of it.

```
    1:53 AM Emulator: compileAndValidateCoreShader: fail to compile. infolog Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: 0:85: error(#143) Undeclared identifier undefined

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: 0:85: error(#132) Syntax error: '<' parse error

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated

1:53 AM Emulator: 

1:53 AM Emulator: linkAndValidateProgram: fail to link program. infolog: Fragment shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram() was called.  Link failed.

1:53 AM Emulator: 

1:53 AM Emulator: compileAndValidateCoreShader: fail to compile. infolog Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: 0:85: error(#143) Undeclared identifier undefined

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: 0:85: error(#132) Syntax error: '<' parse error

1:53 AM Emulator: ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated

1:53 AM Emulator: 

1:53 AM Emulator: linkAndValidateProgram: fail to link program. infolog: Fragment shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram() was called.  Link failed.

1:53 AM Emulator: 

1:53 AM Emulator: glClear:466 GL err 0x502
```

please help me on this. how i can start my emulator

Comment: Your lack of info does not help much, but try to install the SDK and emulators as explained on [this page](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/).